# Getting Value from BoundField in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the value of a BoundField in the codebehind to update to an SQL server but it keeps giving me the old value.

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewtxSLds" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" NullDisplayText="" DataKeyNames="item,AD,BD" CssClass="gridclassscrolledtx" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCreated="gridviewtxSLds_RowCreated" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="m2" HeaderText="Metric" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AD" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="txttime" HeaderText="AD" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BD" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="txttime" HeaderText="BD" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There is a timed button click that fires the following function:

```
 protected void Bulk_Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridviewtxSLds.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        #region textbox declarations
        string txtitem = gridviewtxSLds.DataKeys[i].Values["item"].ToString();
        string txtAD = gridviewtxSLds.DataKeys[i].Values["AD"].ToString();
        string txtBD = gridviewtxSLds.DataKeys[i].Values["BD"].ToString();
        #endregion

        #region command string
        string s = "update D" + timeinitid + "tx set AD";
        s += "='";
        s += txtAD.Trim();
        s += "', ";
        s += "BD";
        s += "='";
        s += txtBD.Trim();
        s += "' where item";
        s += "='";
        s += txtitem.Trim();
        s += "';";
        #endregion
        sb.Append(s.ToString());
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If I change the value in the gridview it still sends the old value to the database. Any idea why?

Comment: You should reissue a databind function after every update for your GridView to refresh its display.

Comment: Where does the data that fills GridView `gridviewtxSLds` come from?

Comment: CurseStacker are you saying just call "DataBind()"?

VDWWD - it's from an SQL database, and the gridview is generated when a name is clicked

Comment: So you are getting data from a database, putting it in a GridView, then reading the data from the GridView, losing the datatype in the process, and saving it again into a database... Your question seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.